# Is it possible to distcp files (comma separated) using distcp between 2 Hdfs directories (separate clusters)?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, distcp

I have the need to only distcp x number of files.

Couldn't find a way to do it.

1. One idea is to copy it over a temporary directory and then *distcp* that directory. Once complete I can delete that temp directory.
2. Individual distcp commands (for each file). This could be painful.

Not sure if comma separation is allowed.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If they have a pattern, you can make use of the wildcards. Please show us sample of the directory structure.

Comment: Just application directories. Imagine spark application history files. /var/log/spark/appHistory/<appId>/. I just need a handful at a time. So wildcards are not super helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either pass all the files as sources to the **`DistCp`** command

```
hadoop distcp hdfs://src_nn/var/log/spark/appHistory/<appId_1>/ \
              hdfs://src_nn/var/log/spark/appHistory/<appId_2>/ \
              ....
              hdfs://src_nn/var/log/spark/appHistory/<appId_n>/ \
              hdfs://dest_nn/target/
```

Or, Create a file containing the list of sources and pass it to the command as source with `-f` option

```
hadoop distcp -f hdfs://src_nn/list_of_files hdfs://dest_nn/target/
```

Comment: Forgot to reply back. But this saved me a lot of trouble. Been using this trick for 5 months in a system. Works. Thanks @franklinsijo

Comment: do we need to do ```kinit``` for both clusters so ```klist``` shows two tickets for both clusters?